# How to write a get endpoint returned data from file multiplied by parameters from query

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I try to write a get endpoint for data from file. I also want to multiply data by parameters from query, unfortunately I get an error. Is there any way to avoid it?

Error I get:
AssertionError at /data/ 'DataView' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method.

```py
# Views.py
class DataView(ListAPIView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        mult = self.request.query_params.get('mult', None)
        y = np.loadtxt('media/data_vv.txt')[:10]
        x = list(range(len(y)))
        print(mult)
        if mult is not None:
            y *= float(mult)

        data = {'x': x, 'y': y}
        return data
```

I want to avoid the error and get the data.

Comment: You need a serializer that will serialize your data to desired output format e.g. `json`, `xml` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#creating-a-serializer-class][1] link to understand how to create a serializer class.

Serializers are basically forms for rest-framework.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I do something wrong, can you see my code which I added?

Answer (score 0):

```py
# models.py
class Data(models.Model):
    data_from_file = models.CharField(max_length=20)

# serializers.py
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = '__all__'

#views.py
class DataView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        mult = self.request.query_params.get('mult', None)
        y = np.loadtxt('media/data_vv.txt')[:10]
        x = list(range(len(y)))

        if mult is not None:
            y *= float(mult)

        y = list(y)
        data = {'x': x, 'y': y}
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        content = Data(data_from_file=content)
        content.save()
        serializer = DataSerializer(content)

        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Now the error is: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `data_from_file` on serializer `DataSerializer`.

I have no idea how to avoid this error.